# How to replace arrow operator(->) with dot(.) operator in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like this

```
s = '''int t; //variable t
t->a=0;  //t->a does;; something
printf("\nEnter the Employee ID : ");
scanf("%d", ptrx->eid);  //employee id ptrx->eid
printf("\nEnter the Employee Name : ");
scanf("%s", ptr->name);
return 0;'''
```

I want to replace `->` this with `.` in above string. But this replacement shouldn't be done inside commments. A comment is a string that starts with `//` and terminates at the end of the line.

I have tried  with below code. Is there any way this can solved using single regular expression.

**Code**

```
import re

for line in s.split('\n'):
    code = re.findall('^(?:(?!\/\/.+$).)*', line)
    comment = re.findall('\/\/.+$', line)
    print(''.join(code).replace('->', '.') + ''.join(comment))
```

**Expected Output:**

```
int t; //variable t
t.a=0;  //t->a does;; something
printf("
Enter the Employee ID : ");
scanf("%d", ptrx.eid);  //employee id ptrx->eid
printf("
Enter the Employee Name : ");
scanf("%s", ptr.name);
return 0;
```

Comment: str.partition should be helpfull here

Comment: @MaxNoe I want a solution using regular expression

Comment: I've been looking for a way to keep `printf("\nEnter the Employee Name : ");` all on one line, but haven't found a way yet

Comment: I haven't found a way to avoid the newline in the text, however, if I place the text in a file and read that, the newline doesn't separate the line.

Comment: @ChrisCharley Thanks I already got that Idea but I don't want to use files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library which allows variable length lookbehind allows the following.

```
>>> s = '''int t; //variable t
t->a=0;  //t->a does;; something
printf("\nEnter the Employee ID : ");
scanf("%d", ptrx->eid);  //employee id ptrx->eid
printf("\nEnter the Employee Name : ");
scanf("%s", ptr->name);
return 0;'''.splitlines()


>>> import regex
>>> for line in s:
    n = regex.sub(r'(?<!//.+)->', '.', line)
    print(n)


int t; //variable t
t.a=0;  //t->a does;; something
printf("
Enter the Employee ID : ");
scanf("%d", ptrx.eid);  //employee id ptrx->eid
printf("
Enter the Employee Name : ");
scanf("%s", ptr.name);
return 0;
>>>
```